# JQuery background color

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery Autocomplete on my ASP.net page.  I am not sure how to change the backgroud color of the AutoComplete.  Right now, it displays the list with "Clear" background.

Where can i change the background color?  (And, I am wondering why it's not taking the default settings. I downloaded the jQuery from JQueryUI website).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery Autocomplete control uses a series of Themeroller styles for presentation:

- ul: ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all
- li: ui-menu-item
- a: ui-corner-all

You could either add a custom style for `ui-autocomplete li` or `ui-autocomplete a`.  There doesn't appear to be a way to define your own purpose-built styles as part of the control.

The likely best way to define the background colour is by overriding the `.ui-menu .ui-menu-item` style.

Answer (score 1):

If you use an jquery autocomplete with a css search this:

```
.ui-state-hover, 
.ui-widget-content 
.ui-state-hover, 
.ui-widget-header, 
.ui-state-hover, 
.ui-state-focus, 
.ui-widget-content, 
.ui-state-focus, 
.ui-widget-header, 
.ui-state-focus 
     { 
       border: 1px solid #999999/*{borderColorHover}*/; 
       background: #dadada /*{bgColorHover}*/ url(images/ui-bg_glass_75_dadada_1x400.png)/*{bgImgUrlHover}*/ 50%/*{bgHoverXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgHoverYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgHoverRepeat}*/;   
       font-weight: normal/*{fwDefault}*/; color: #212121/*{fcHover}*/; 
     }

.ui-state-hover a, 
.ui-state-hover a:hover, 
.ui-state-hover a:link, 
.ui-state-hover a:visited 
     { 
       color: #212121/*{fcHover}*/; 
       text-decoration: none; 
     }
```

Change `#dadada` with your desired color.